# Which is proper: "to debate X" or "to debate about X"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, transitive-verbs

Which version of this sentence is correct?

> - Doctoral students about to graduate, like me, often **debate about** what qualities make a successful scientist.
> - Doctoral students about to graduate, like me, often **debate** what qualities make a successful scientist.

Comment: I think "debate about" is more common.

Comment: @rayn: What planet do you live on? The form *debate about* barely exists at all in a global context - I find it hard to believe it's actually "more common" in *any* specific community of native speakers.

Comment: What a bizarrely angry comment. I also think "debate about" is more common, at least in my own community (though you may argue that a community of British students is not any particular authority on anything). I find it hard to make this sensibly google-able, though, firstly because "debate about" is still correct when "debate" is a noun, but secondly also because "debate about" is clearly more colloquial than "debate".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, while I normally find your instincts about things like this spot-on, I think you're generalizing inappropriately from your personal experience here. While I don't hear it as often as the other form, I **definitely** hear people say "debate about" regularly. It sounds a little uneducated, but it's clearly something that native speakers say.

Comment: Also, "we debated" returns 512,000 google hits and "we debated about" 419,000. The results for the latter all sound natural to me, albeit informal. Here are some examples from the first page:

"We debated about Math" (title of an m4w on Craigslist)
"Question we debated about at work today" (title of a forum thread)
"We debated about whether to post this one" (preceding a gruesome image)
"Remember that surrogate mother we debated about?"

Actually, to me, that last one REQUIRES "about". Without "about", it means that the speaker engaged in a debate against the surrogate mother.

Comment: @alcas: I'm certainly not saying I never come across the usage. But I just don't believe there's anything you could call a coherent linguistic community where it's the *more common form*, as claimed by rayn.

Comment: @alcas: I'd also just add that whilst I can see a Google search does indeed return those numbers, I think it must reflect a weakness in their "gestimate results" algorithm. Clearly every instance of *"we debated **about**"* also matches *"we debated"*, so if the figures are accurate we should expect 80% of all matches for the latter to be followed by the word *"about"*. But I had to page through 60 results before I found the first *"debated **about**"* in the hits for *we debated*. I can't say exactly why, but your Google hit counts are definitely misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using 'debate' as a noun, you use 'about'~ "There will be a debate about [sth]"

If you are using 'debate' as a verb, you don't use 'about' ~ "They will debate [sth]"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to say *"debate **about**"* is exactly "wrong", because there's no incontrovertible principle of grammar to back that position up. But to be honest if I heard it, I'd downgrade my opinion of the speaker's linguistic competence.

Note that [they debated whether](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20debated%20whether%22&oq=%22they%20debated%20whether%22&gs_l=serp.3...4611.5467.5.5771.6.6.0.0.0.0.147.394.5j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.HTFZhlMM5W8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886) [to do this, that, or the other], has 11,700 hits in Google Books - compared to 87 for ["they debated **about** whether"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20debated%20about%20whether%22&oq=%22they%20debated%20about%20whether%22&gs_l=serp.3...78635.80289.6.80739.6.6.0.0.0.0.80.389.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.WzKNW6WW9Lo&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886) (i.e. - it's *definitely* "non-standard").

[Here's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debated%20what,debated%20about%20what&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) the broad picture on OP's usage...
[image]

I assume the reason we see this form at all is that because some people think that if...

> [they **debated** far into the night](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20debated%20far%20into%20the%20night%22&oq=%22they%20debated%20far%20into%20the%20night%22&gs_l=serp.3...197037.200075.7.200635.3.3.0.0.0.0.75.163.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1j2.qOxmWY-oJE8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886) = [they **talked** far into the night](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20talked%20far%20into%20the%20night%22&oq=%22they%20talked%20far%20into%20the%20night%22&gs_l=serp.3...57337.60983.8.61409.15.13.0.0.0.2.118.879.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.pgMrfWfWJ2s&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886)

...and...

> [we **talked** politics](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22we%20talked%20politics%22&oq=%22we%20talked%20politics%22&gs_l=serp.3...15684.16404.18.17205.4.4.0.0.0.0.55.205.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.iL_JWHu7CXw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886) = ["we **talked about** politics"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22we%20debated%20about%20what%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22we%20talked%20about%20politics%22&oq=%22we%20talked%20about%20politics%22&gs_l=serp.3...43529.45201.19.45656.6.6.0.0.0.0.67.343.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.M91z3bxPGs8&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1de1b7c73b3438dd&biw=1379&bih=886)

...they can extrapolate to *we debated **about** [some topic]*. Personally, I think such people are probably either careless or ignorant, regardless of whatever supposed "rules" of grammar apply. If nearly everyone uses one form, it's perverse to use another.

Comment: You're making the extrapolation seem more far-fetched than it should. It probably just stems from the fact that "debate about" is fine when "debate" is a noun: "I can't stand the debate about whether vaccines cause autism", or similar.

Comment: @alcas: I don't see what the noun usage has to do with it. Historically, *"a debate **on**"* is three times more common than *"a debate **about**"*, but I don't think anyone would see that as justification for OP using *"on"*. People normally just ["debate whether XXXX"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debated+on+whether%2Cdebated+about+whether%2Cdebated+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), not *"on/about whether XXXX"*. But you can't say they are having *"a debate XXXX"* - you ***need*** a preposition *(on, about, over)* before XXXX there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The beginning part of your answer should have been the only thing here. The rest of your answer is nothing more than a matter of your personal preference.

Comment: @Souta: It's not just *my personal preference* - it's overwhelmingly the majority opinion, as the usage figures clearly show.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Regardless, the basis is "it is a matter of preference". It doesn't mean that it is wrong. Why does everyone think that just because the majority say it differently, that the lesser-spoken is automatically wrong only on the foundation that it is 'not as used'? Furthermore, to add in your own tidbit about how you'd find someone using that phrase, you'd `downgrade my opinion of the speaker's linguistic competence` and then say `Personally, I think such people are probably either careless or ignorant`. That was completely unnecessary and VERY rude.

Comment: @Souta: That is *your* opinion, just as it's *my* opinion that if well under 1% of the Anglophone population use a particular form, it very likely has implications for the linguistic competence of that minority. It seems to me that either you're implying all speakers are of equal competence, or you think that *this particular* "non-standard usage" is somehow exempt from the general principle that competent speakers tend to use the same forms as other competent speakers in cases where rules of grammar don't hold complete sway.

Comment: No, @FumbleFingers, I'm saying that if there is NO rule being broken when saying `debate about` - or anything for that matter where no rule is being explicitly broken - then who are you to say that they're somehow inferior to you? If anything, I think you have one massively inflated ego and need to back off. How about that for an opinion?

Comment: @Souta: You'll note that I also have said repeatedly in both my answer and comments that there's no "rule of grammar" involved here. Your own answer says that *"debate **about** sounds quirky"* - which can only mean **you don't hear it often**, since you can't say it breaks any rule apart from the general principle that competent speakers normally use the standard idiomatic form. But let's leave it at that, since we're obviously not moving towards any commonality of opinion here.

Comment: No, but now I'll have to ask you... Would you say "We debated about personal preferences in the English language" or "We debated personal preferences in the English language"? (Only thing I agree with, is that not everyone is competent... what I just can't agree with, is you saying that someone is automatically 'lesser' just because they use something that isn't common.) But I agree, we'll drop it now. Fun debate! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The verb can be used with an object and without, so it is both. Either is therefore correct.

Comment: -1 The fact that you can say *"John and I debated for hours"* (intransitive, no object) and *"John and I debated the issue for hours"* (transitive, object = *the issue*) has no bearing on whether people actually say *"John and I debated **about** the issue for hours"*. They normally don't.

Comment: Well I suppose we could debate about that, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

While using **about** isn't wrong, I'm agreeing with everyone saying it is quirky *sounding*. Normally one would say

> I like to debate politics.
>
> She constantly debates over debates.
>
> We love debating the lifestyles between cats and dogs; I personally feel like cats have it better.
>
> I just finished a debate with a friend, arguing if marijuana should be legalized.

For your example:

> Doctoral students about to graduate, like me, often debate what qualities make a successful scientist.

That sounds fine as it is. This sentence [imho], **about** would seem superfluous.